# Heat Equation Mixed Boundaries Case: Fourier Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I was working on the heat equation:
$$\mu_t= \alpha \mu_{xx}$$
$$\mu(0,t)=0$$
$$\mu_x(L,t)=0$$
$$\mu(x,0)=f(x)$$

I arrived at the following solution:
$$\mu=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }b_me^{\frac{-\alpha ^2(2m-1)^2\pi^2}{4L^2}t}\sin(\frac{(2m-1)\pi x}{2L})$$

So $\mu(x,0)=f(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }b_m\sin(\frac{(2m-1)\pi x}{2L})$
I am now stuck since I have no clue how to extend f(x) to a sine fourier series with new L = 2*L. So how do I calculate $b_m$ ? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about the orthogonality rules for sine? For example, do you know what
$$ \frac{1}{4L}\int_{-2L}^{2L} \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(2m-1)\pi x}{2L}\right) dx$$ is for some integer $n$?

Comment: As mentioned above, the set of this sine functions forms a complete basis of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, so $b_{m}$'s are given by the inner product $b_{m}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\int_{-2L}^{2L}f(x)\sin\Big(\frac{m\pi{x}}{L}\Big)dx$

Comment: I've tried using that with 2L instead of L for f(x)=40-x. 0<=x<=L=40 Somehow, I ended up getting 0 for b_m. So, I'm still not sure what went wrong by 2*integral from 0 to 2L=80.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a Fourier Sine series, you will need to use an odd $2L = 80$ periodic extension of $f(x)$. Define
$$
f_o(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & 0\leq x \leq 80 \\
-f(-x) & -80 \leq x <0
\end{cases}.
$$
Notice that in general this defines an odd function about $x=0$ and because your function is already odd about $x=40$, this extension gives an odd extension about $x=\pm40$. In general the extension would have to be
$$
f_0(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & 0 \leq x <L \\
-f(-x) & -L \leq x < 0\\
-f(-x-2L) & L\leq x \leq 2L\\ 
f(x+2L) & -2L \leq x < -L.
\end{cases}
$$
Now you should multiply both sides of your equation for $\mu(x,0) = f(x)$ by $\sin(m\pi x/(2L))$ and integrate from $-2L$ to $2L$. You will have to split the integral involving $f(x)$ up into two cases, but it should turn out nonzero. The orthogonality of the sines on the other side of the equation will define your $b_m$, only for odd $m$ of course!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still didnot get how to compute $b_m$ in the above question, what is the integration formula? I it  $ \frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) sin(\frac{(2m-1) \pi x}{2L})$ ?