# Mixed boundary condition for the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, linear-pde

Would someone help me understand the way the solution obtained in this question: 
[Heat Equation Mixed Boundaries Case: Fourier Coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167928/heat-equation-mixed-boundaries-case-fourier-coefficients)

I did not understand why  in the final solution, he took $b_m$ and not  $b_{2m-1}$. I am confused not just because of the rank of the coefficients, this is because according to this rank $$b_m= \frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) sin\Big(\frac{m \pi x}{2L}\Big)$$ or 
$$b_{2m-1}= \frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) \sin\Big(\frac{(2m-1) \pi x}{2L}\Big)$$

Sorry if I appear much confused, but  I really want to understand it.
Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Use `$\sin$` for $\sin$ (instead of `$sin$` for $sin$).

Comment: Both formulas are equivalent. The first one restricts the subscript $m$ to odd integers; the second one doesn't.